# why is password field showing masked value when html form is loaded?(only in firefox)

Tags: html, firefox, forms, passwords

the password field in the html form i have created for my webpage is displayed some masked value which i believe is the password value that im using to connect to my database(same number of characters). But the problem is only for firefox: ie and chrome is displaying correctly.
ive also tried setting the password value to null (""), it didnt help either. 
The variable name for sql password, post etc are different.

this is the code...

```
<div id="logincont">
<div id="loginfrm">
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="index.php">
<table class="logintable">
<tr>
<td width="70px"><span class="fonts"> Username</span></td><td><input type="text" name="user" id="userfield" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="70px"><span class="fonts"> Password</span></td><td><input type="password" name="pass" id="passfield" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</td></tr></table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

n even after clearing the cache n cookies too, its showing the same thing..

Comment: Did you let firefox remember the password?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML? Obviously you should remove the actual password first.

Comment: Try re-naming the form field to ensure that Firefox hasn't remembered it. Or alternatively, clear all saved passwords (from memory you can do this by pressing Ctrl - Shift - Delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove saved passwords in FireFox, go to Tools -> Options, Security tab, click the Saved Passwords button, and remove the saved passwords that you want removed. Also, if you have browser toolbars or add-ons, some of them may save passwords and auto-fill them into forms. I think that the Google Toolbar does this as well, so you may need to look at the security options for that, in addition to the FireFox options.

Comment: i havent used any password b4.. even wen loaded for the first time, its showing like that.. n der isnt any password stored

Comment: besides, the username field is empty, only the password field is filled, that too with the wrong password

Comment: On the server side, what value for the password field gets submitted to your index.php when submitted from FireFox?

Comment: solved it.. the password ws stored for wampserver n it ws getting displayed..thanks for the help :)